# Undefined reference to Template Static Function

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

What is wrong with this code !!!!
undefined reference to `bool BioQt::QSequenceValidator::IsValidDNASequence(BioQt::QSequence)'

```
   class QSequenceValidator
{


public:

    template<class SEQ>
    static bool IsValidDNASequence(SEQ seq);
}

template<class SEQ>
bool IsValidDNASequence(SEQ seq)
{
    foreach (QChar c ,seq)
    {
        if(!CompoundSet::DNACompoundSet().contains(c,Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            return FALSE;

    }
    return TRUE;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  qDebug()<<QSequenceValidator::IsValidDNASequence(pop);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `QSequenceValidator::` before `IsValidDNASequence` definition. Currently you are defining free function, not static member function. i.e.

```
template<class SEQ>
bool QSequenceValidator::IsValidDNASequence(SEQ seq)
{
  ...
}
```